# Is a Google Search Appliance feed added in realtime?

Tags: google-search-appliance

How long after a document is fed to the Google Search Appliance using a content feed can I
expect to see the document in the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from my own experience it seems to vary somewhere between 1 and 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see mine come up after about 5 minutes, but sometimes it can be an hour. It depends on what the GSA is working on at the time your feed comes in. If it's crawling other pages, then it might be a while. This is one of those things we can't control. If it's important that things show up more quickly, try to schedule your site crawling and data feeds at different times.